# In VBA i am getting error 1004 when i run a piece of code twice

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have the following piece of code:

```
Dim objexcel1 As excel.Application
Dim wbexcel1 As excel.Workbook
Dim objSht1 As excel.Worksheet
Set objexcel1 = CreateObject("excel.Application")
'objexcel1.Visible = True 'Remove excel visibilty at start


Set wbexcel1 = objexcel1.Workbooks.Open("C:\CARS.xls")
Set objSht1 = wbexcel1.Worksheets("car")
objSht1.Activate


Columns("A:B").Select

Charts.Add
ActiveChart.chartType = xlXYScatter
```

I need to run this code twice. When I run it first it runs properly but on the second run it gives me an error  1004 on `Columns("A:B").Select`

Answer (score 0):

yes i got it i need to add references.

Comment: Please expand on your answer. What references do you need to add? Where? What does the fixed code look like?